# Rails module works for some time - then stops working from my controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, controller

I have modified `application.rb` to autoload my lib directory:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

I have defined a module `X::Y` in the file `lib/x/y.rb` with a function `execute(param)`.

In a controller (`A::B`), I call execute in this file by including the file and then calling the function:

```
require 'x/y'
results = X::Y.execute(param)
```

This works perfectly for a short while after the application is loaded but quickly I start getting the error:

```
NameError in A::B#index
uninitialized constant A::B::X
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the actual names of `X` and `Y`, and the actual path name corresponding to `x/y.rb` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to move these into the model for ease.